# Is there any precedent of technology falling into the hands of the Chinese or Russians through Israel?

Tags: united-states, israel, espionage

Is there any precedent of technology falling into the hands of the Chinese or Russians through Israel?

https://www.timesofisrael.com/trump-approves-selling-f-22-raptor-to-israel-report/

> US Secretary of Defense Mark Esper told Israeli officials during a
> visit to Israel this week that the Trump administration has approved
> selling F-22 stealth fighters to the Jewish state, according to a
> Friday report in a Saudi-owned newspaper.
>
> US President Donald Trump okayed the sale of the F-22 Raptor and
> precision-guided bombs to Israel, the London-based Asharq Al-Awsat
> newspaper reported, citing senior sources in Tel Aviv.
>
> **Such a sale would first require the US Congress to overturn a current
> law barring Washington from exporting the advanced fighter jets. The
> House of Representatives passed the law in 1998 over concerns that the
> nigh-unparalleled stealth technology in the F-22 could fall into the
> hands of Russia or China if the aircraft were sold abroad, including
> to Israel.**

https://www.timesofisrael.com/trump-approves-selling-f-22-raptor-to-israel-report/

There's a law barring the U.S. from exporting F22 to Israel or any country, and the reason given is that the technology could fall into the hands of the Russian or Chinese if the deal gets through, including Israel. However, Israel is perhaps the closest American ally, so I was wondering if there was a precedent of Israel leaking technology or Israel getting compromised by Russian or Chinese spies.

Comment: I don't think they're concerned about Israel intentionally leaking the technology, but about being more vulnerable to Russia/China stealing it from them.

Comment: The US might be Israel's closest ally, but I don't think you'd say that Israel was the US's closest ally.

Comment: Do you mean "precedent" or "incident"?  I think the latter word may be a better fit for what you are asking.

Comment: Israel have, since 1992 until the end of the century, been supporting China's military development. They give China their suicide drones, have attempted to develop with/sell AWAG aircraft to china, and there are rumors that the data from their cancelled Lavi fighter program eventually went to China and became what is now J-10